# TEI header - cannot parse (SAXON)

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, tei

I have a TEI P5 valid xml file and I already successfully used Saxon-PE 9 to parse the file.

However, I am unable to get the 'biblStruct/monogr/imprint/date' value.

As far as I got - the parser is not recognizing 'sourceDesc' node, but it does recognize 'titleStmt', which is in the same hierarchical level.
Would anyone know, what is the solution to my problem?

Specifically:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:titleStmt">
```

does work, but

```
<xsl:template match="tei:biblStruct">
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="tei:biblStruct/tei:monogr/tei:imprint/tei:date">
```

doesn't. That said, the ouput is null, and the `<xsl:message>Parser successfully got here.</xsl:message>` is not triggered at all.

This would be the header of XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Zaveza</title>
                <title>Revija</title>
                <title>Elektronska </title>
            </titleStmt>
            <editionStmt>
                <edition>0.1</edition>
            </editionStmt>
            <extent> KB XML </extent>
            <publicationStmt>
                <publisher>
                    <address>
                    </address>
                </publisher>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <biblStruct>
                    <monogr>
                        <title>Zaveza</title>
                        <imprint>
                            <biblScope type="issue">10</biblScope>
                            <biblScope type="vol">XXVI</biblScope>
                            <biblScope>številka 4, december 2016</biblScope>
                            <date when="2016-12">2016</date>
                        </imprint>
                    </monogr>
                </biblStruct>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
    </teiHeader>
--
</TEI>
```

And this is the part of the XLS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

                xmlns:rng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
                xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
                xmlns:teix="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/Examples"

                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0"
                exclude-result-prefixes="a fo rng tei teix">

    <doc xmlns="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl">
        <desc>Process element teiHeader</desc>
    </doc>
    <xsl:template match="tei:date">
        <xsl:message>Parser successfully got here.</xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll get better responses if you describe your problem better.  The code you show doesn't  include anything that attempts to retrieve the date element you say you are having trouble with; your question doesn't tell us what error message or result you are getting and how that result differs from what you expected.  Make yourself easier to help; see [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice.

Comment: You've shown us enough code for us to know that you've understood the basic principle that element names have to be qualified by a prefix bound to the correct namespace; nevertheless, if you'd shown the missing code that isn't working, I would first check that you have used namespace prefixes consistently throughout and haven't forgotten one.

Comment: Thank you, @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen and MichaelKay, I tried to redefine question and I specified the problem (no output) again.

Comment: @pishcotec_a there is apparently a typo in your revised text:  you say that `match="tei:titleStmt"` works but `match="tei:titleStmt"` does not work.  Copy/paste error?  And you still have not provided a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your prose mentions a `message` element, but I don't see one in the code you posted.  Try to make the smallest possible stylesheet that reproduces the puzzling behavior and lets us see why you're puzzled.  With the stylesheet you provide, the date element is in fact processed by the template you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, given your revised question, is that the template rule is never activated because you never invoke `xsl:apply-templates` on the relevant nodes. For a template rule to have any effect, two conditions must be satisfied: you must select the relevant nodes for processing (in an `xsl:apply-templates` `select` expression), and the template rule must match those nodes (and be the highest priority/precedence template rule for those nodes).

Comment: In the meantime, I have come to the same conclusion - the template was never activated.
> and be the highest priority/precedence template rule for those nodes
I think this is/was my problem. The actual TEI stylesheet is quite long and I did not find my way through it.
I succeded my attept by creating a new element, and just pulled the needed information from `tei:date` element.

Answer (score 1):

Given the input and XSLT stylesheet you provide, I am unable to replicate your problem.  The stylesheet you provide does produce output when run on the input shown (once the well-formedness error in the input is fixed and the end-tag for the `xsl:stylesheet` element is provided), and the template for `tei:date` does in fact process the date element in the input.  This is easily seen in the output from the fact that the content of the element does not appear in the output:  that is what the template shown is written to do.

So:  either the stylesheet and input you showed are really what you are using, in which case you should be seeing error messages complaining of non-XML input (and an invalid stylesheet, owing to the bad comment in the XSLT you show), *or* you have abbreviated the stylesheet in a way that removes the problem. In the latter case you now know that the problem is in the material you removed; that's something.

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, I tried the other way round, without calling the template (I was still unable to do).